# horizontal menu / 4-level depth

Tags: menus, wp-list-pages

I need a 4-level horizontal menu. 
which is the best way to build, organize and style it? "Active" tabs should be highlighted.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('include=137,693,139,147&title_li='); ?>
```

I am new to using `wp_nav_menu();`. 
I have built 2-level `wp_list_pages();` menus.

Answer (score 1):

You will get better results and more control using the wp_nav_menu function as it allows you to control the menu items.

Comment: look into Twenty Eleven how the menu is done there. it also has the full css for a horizontal dropdown menu.